# Which design pattern is recommended when implementations only differ in a single method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have an interface with 6 methods used to manage datasets. The only method that differs between implementations is `getSerializedVersion()` and the constructor that is able to parse the serialization string.

```
public interface DataSets {
  public void addEntry(...);
  public void  removeEntry(...);
  public void manipulateEntry(...);
  public SomeType getEntry(...);
  public List<SomeType> getAllEntries();
  // This differs:
  public String getSerializedVersion()
}
```

I can't change the Interface.

My first idea was to generate an abstract class and implement the first five methods. For the concrete implementations (e.g. `DataSetsXML`, `DataSetsYAML`, ...) I only have to implement `getSerializedVersion()` and the constructor that that is able to read the String and initialize the object.

To make it more testable a different design might be better (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7569581) but which one?

Answers might be subjective, but I think there are some general rules or a least (objective) advantages and disadvantages of the different approaches,...

Comment: You could use a single class, and delegate to a Serializer, passed as argument to the constructor, to implement getSerializedVersion(). Have N implementations of Serializer (YamlSerializer, XmlSerializer, etc.)

Comment: @JBNizet's answer is the way to go. From a class responsibility perspective, serializing seems like a different job than managing the dataset. No need to use an abstract class and further encode this design mistake, imo.

Comment: @JBNizet: Can you write an answer from your comment.

Comment: @Edward It wouldn't be much different from Jack's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what you explain the difference is something that is not related to the behavior of the class but just how it is serialized and unserialized. What I mean is that the `DataSetsXML` and `DataSetsYAML` would have the same identical funcionality but they would be serialized into different formats.

This means that there is no benefit in keeping `getSerializedVersion()` coupled with the `DataSets` class. You should totally decouple them.

You could have a serialization interface sort of:

```
interface DataSetsSerializer
{
  public DataSets unserialize(String string);
  public String serialize(DataSets sets);
}
```

and then take care of differente implementations just in this class, eg:

```
class YAMLDataSetsSerializer implements DataSetsSerializer
{
  public DataSets unserialize(String string) {
    DataSets sets = new DataSets();
    ...
  }

  public String serialize(DataSets sets) {
    ...
  }
}
```

By elaborating on JB Nizet comment, if you have to keep a `DataSetsSerializer` inside a `DataSets` instance (which IMHO makes no sense since they should be decoupled in any case, as a specific way of serialization shouldn't be bound to the data to be serialized) then the approach would be the following:

```
class DataSets {
  final private DataSetsSerializer serializer;

  public DataSets(DataSetsSerializer serializer, String data) {
    this.serializer = serializer;
    serializer.unserialize(this, data);
  }

  @Override
  public String getSerializedVersion() {
    return serializer.serialize(this);
  }
}
```

This requires a slight change in the proposed interface and it's not a clever design but it respects your requirements.

Comment: Since he can't change the interface I would also add that he should throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` with a message about using these serializers when `getSerializedVersion` is called.

Comment: I agree with decoupling the serialization. But then the API user needs to hold two references - one for the `DataSets` and one for the serialization. (Please correct me if I'm wrong). I guess that's why the Interface as been defined as it is. So probably the solution from `JB Nizet`'s comment (Delegate to a serializer added via the constructor) is the way to go in my case. Or do you see any disadvantage of that approach?

Comment: Would be great if you discuss `JB Nizet`'s comment in your answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Edward: I added a specific description of his solution, which is basically mine but with a tighter coupling.

Comment: @Jack: Thanks,... So in you preferred solution, complete decoupling requires references to the `serializer` and to the `dataset`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, which allows you, for example to unserialize a data set with a format, modify it and the serialize it with another format, since the two things are unrelated.

Comment: @Jack: You're right. I haven't thought about that (since in my case it is not needed) I'll add this to you answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is reasonable to use an abstract class. You can test the concrete implementations of the abstract class (which indirectly tests the abstract class as well).