# Partial mocking of class with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I want to mock only the `GetValue` method of the following class, using Moq:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        int value = GetValue();
        Console.WriteLine("ORIGINAL MyMethod: " + value);
    }

    internal virtual int GetValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ORIGINAL GetValue");
        return 10;
    }
}
```

I already read a bit how this should work with Moq. The solution that I found online is to use the `CallBase` property, but that doesn't work for me.

This is my test:

```
[Test]
public void TestMyClass()
{
     var my = new Mock<MyClass> { CallBase = true };
     my.Setup(mock => mock.GetValue()).Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("MOCKED GetValue")).Returns(999);
     my.Object.MyMethod();
     my.VerifyAll();
 }
```

I would expect that Moq uses the existing implementation of `MyMethod` and calls the mocked method, resulting in the following output:

```
ORIGINAL MyMethod: 999
MOCKED GetValue
```

but that's what I get :

```
ORIGINAL GetValue
ORIGINAL MyMethod: 10
```

and then

```
Moq.MockVerificationException : The following setups were not matched: MyClass mock => mock.GetValue()
```

I got the feeling, that I misunderstood something completely. What am I missing here?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [When mocking a class with Moq, how can I CallBase for just specific methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822947/when-mocking-a-class-with-moq-how-can-i-callbase-for-just-specific-methods)

Comment: If you make your `GetValue` method `public` instead of `internal` it works. I don't know why maybe this is a limitation of castle dynamic proxy, or is it a bug a Moq, or this is the intended behavior. Anyway if you leave it as internal you cannot put your production code to a different assembly unless you use InternalVisibleTo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying a method was called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980108/verifying-a-method-was-called)

Comment: well, it really does work if I change `GetValue`to `public`. That's a real bummer. I've got a very complex class that uses a private method to write its result to an ascii-file. I only wanted to get rid of that file and check the string directly in my unit test. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to this in another question: [How to Mock the Internal Method of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772621/how-to-mock-the-internal-method-of-a-class). So this is a duplicate and can be closed.

Nevertheless, here's the solution:
just add this line to the `Assembly.config` of the project you want to test:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")] // namespace in Moq
```

Comment: To the test's Assembly.config? Or to the class being tested's Assembly.config?

Comment: Of the class that's being tested! I edited my answer and clarified that bit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify Verifiable:

```
my.Setup(mock => mock.GetValue()).Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("MOCKED GetValue")).Returns(999).Verifiable();
```

Comment: didn't try it, but it makes no difference